# How can I disconnect a client user from a domain and connect it to another?

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2008, windows

I maintain a small network with 5 client computers and a Small Business Server 2003. Now the server is broken. I have installed a new server with Small Business Server 2008. How do I connect an exid sting client to the new server?

E.g. I can still login on the client computers (e.g with username `OLDDOMAIN\Jonas`), but the server is down and the client is "connected" to the old domain. Is there any way I can connect this user to the new server, and when the client is connected to the new server I would like to synchronize "My Documents" to the new server.

How can I do this? Is it just to login on to an existing client (e.g. with username `OLDDOMAIN\Jonas`) and then type `http://connect.newdomain.local`? Or should I login to the local administrator account on the computer and then type `http://connect.newdomain.local`? ...can I login to both the old `OLDDOMAIN\Jonas` and the new domain `NEWDOMAIN\Jonas` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the above will work as you intend.  Essentially you are talking about doing a domain migration and it will not be as simple as you have described.  Each active directory account has a SID, a unique identifier to the account.  This SID is used for things like file permissions, group membership, etc and when creating a new account in the new domain the SID will be different.

In most instances I would recommend doing a simple domain trust and account migration, but in SBS I don't believe you can setup the trusts needed for this without a bit of "hacking".

For your scenario I would recommend using User State Migration Tool, which can migrate files/settings from one computer to another.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4AF2D2C9-F16C-4C52-A203-8DAF944DD555

In your scenario make sure to run a backup before changing anything, and run USMT.  Following that login as local administrator, remove it from the old domain and add it to the new domain, then use USMT again to import the data.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This sounds like a complicated solution. Do I have to run this migration tool on the old server (that is broken and doesn't start)? Can't I just create new accounts on the new server and then copy the "My Documents" folder to the new client account?

Comment: While it may sounds complicated the User State Migration Tool is fairly straight forward.  Googling around about it might give you more information than just the download piece.  You can just create new accounts and copy my documents, but remember this won't migrate all settings and in some environments people can be most upset if their desktop wallpaper isnt the same as it used to be.